# Leaking stop valve

Tags: plumbing

I just got done replacing 3 stop valves under a sink, I tuned the water back on and 2 were fine, but one had water coming out.

After tightening up the compression nut I got it to stop, but there is still enough to drip occasionally.  I have a small plastic bowl under it.  When I run my fingers over it, I feel water on the back side.

Could I have over tightened it?   If so can I just replace the ferrule?
Dont want to leave it as is, as the hard water will corrode the outside of the valve around the copression fitting.

Comment: Once a ferrule has been compressed   it must be cut off to replace it, do you have enough pipe to do that?  Are you using two wrenches, one to tighten the nut and one to hold the valve? Sometimes it just takes another quarter turn to seat it.

Comment: Oh I tightened it more the first time it was leaking when I turned the water back on, but I think I might have over-tightened.  I used channel lock pliers to remove the old ferrule by griping and twisting.  Then I sanded off the end of the copper.

Comment: I might have used too much plumbers tape on the valve threads, or it was uneven. Either way, Im gonna take it off and re-install soon. I have extra ferrules.

Comment: A compression fitting that uses ferrules does not require teflon tape on the threads. The seal happens at the ferrule and not the threads- they are merely there to tighten the valve against the ferrule. The teflon tape may be in the way. I actually add a drop of sewing machine oil to the threads so it tightens easier and smoother. And, yes you can certainly overtighten these so take care...

Answer (score 2):

> I might have used too much plumbers tape on the valve threads, or it
> was uneven. Either way, I'm gonna take it off and re-install soon.

Ahhh, important missing information.

**You do not use  Teflon tape on compression/ferrule  fittings**.

The ferrule does the sealing, no tape or pipe dope should be used.

Take the tape off and see if it will seat properly.

You may have to start over with a fresh end on the copper pipe if the end was miss-formed or otherwise compromised by the ferrule or the removal of the ferrule with pliers. The fact that you were able to pull it off means it was not seated properly, probably because of the tape interfering.